# Solving a recurrence relation using iteration method

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

how to solve `T(n) = T(n-1) + n` using Iterative method and answer is `theta(n^2)`

Answer (score 7):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n = T(n-2) + n-1 + n = ... = 1+ 2 + ... + n = (n+1)n/2 = theta(n^2)
```

note the assumption that T(0) = 0 (you must have base for the recursion)

 hope that what you have meant

Answer (score 1):

At times, you could also use characteristics equations method to solve recurrence relations. This involves determining Particular integral and total solution.

More information here: [solving recurrence relations](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs504/f00/notes/recurrence/solve/solve.html)